# How Should I use the PCL in QT4 with qmake and without cmake

Tags: qt, qmake, point-cloud-library

I just started with the point cloud library (plc), but I have many problems trying to integrate this library in my QT4 project under Windows (with MSV 2010 compiler).

The main problem is to use the PCL with qmake and QT4. I haven't had much experience with this kind of implementation.

My first goal is to integrate and run the PCL visualizer. Thanks for any help! The best way to help me is to show me a runnable *.pro file with all added PCL includes as well as libraries.

Comment: Have you added third party libs and includepath to .pro?

Comment: Have you read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the same platform as you do. However, I think the easiest way is by using cmake wizard in Qt creator. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065984/embedding-pcl-viewer-on-a-qt-gui-main-window/22878015#22878015) on a similar question. Hope it will help to build Qt GUI project in no time.