# Embedding PCL Viewer on a Qt GUI Main Window

Tags: qt, point-cloud-library

I am trying to develop a user interface using QtCreator on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. This user interface will be deployed on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine, and will control a projector and a camera for a structured-light application. For reasons beyond my control (compatibility with camera and projector's APIs), I will use the MS VS 2010 32bit compiler for this. After a couple of weeks trying to have everything I need working together (Qt 4.8.4, QtCreator and Point Cloud Library), I am now facing a slight problem.

Is there a way that I can embed the PCL Point Cloud Viewer inside my main Qt GUI window? The problem is that when I use the PCL viewer, it brings up a separate window. I want this window to be embedded inside my main window, and I want to still be able to interact with it (rotate, pan, zoom, etc.).

As you may be able to tell from my post, I am a newbie on Qt/PCL/etc., so any example with minimal code to do this would be greatly appreciated. I have done weeks of research on this and I have not been able to find a solution, although I get the impression that a Qt Widget might be the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use PCL's [PCLVisualizer](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html), which is extensively described [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php), via the [QVTKWidget](http://old.compucell3d.org/Documentation/class_q_v_t_k_widget.html). This is the setup I'm currently running. So you would end up doing something along the lines of the following (pseudo-)code:

In your header:

```
class PointCloudWidget : public QVTKWidget
{
    //Whatever comes before (constructor, methods, etc.)

private:

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer m_visualizer;
};
```

And in your cpp:

```
PointCloudWidget::PointCloudWidget(QWidget *parent) : QVTKWidget(parent)
{
    this->SetRenderWindow(m_visualizer.getRenderWindow());
}
```

You can then use the visualizer to achieve the same functionality as the PCL viewer has.

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918650/how-to-visualize-a-sequence-of-tof-sensor-data-in-pcl-with-qt/11939703#11939703) are some more detailed code.

Comment: This fails with PCL 1.9.1 and vtk 8.2 due to incomplete type of `vtkRenderWindow`. Which versions was this compiled against?

Comment: Update: Apparently, one mus `#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>` in addition to the pcl headers, to make the error go away. Maybe the `pcl_visualizer.h` header only uses forward declarations.

Comment: Note that this is not functional with VTK >= 9

Answer (score 0):

Look at the kind of minimal code I put [here (PCL Viewer with Qt GUI minimal code)](https://gist.github.com/Logrus/9988524).
There are some redundancies, but the code I believe is pretty straightforward.

The main idea is to put the files in the one folder and start project from CMakeLists.txt (Qt cmake wizard).

I use `build` directory inside project dir. (this is important, because in `pclwindow.cpp` I hardcoded the path to the generated file `#include "build/ui_pclwindow.h"`

If app builds, but crashes you'll probably need to add some dependencies (e.g. dll files on Win platform)

I hope it will give you fast and simple start!