# Using PCL with QT Creator

Tags: qt, point-cloud-library

I am noob on PCL, I can't Configure QT Creator For PCL in windows. 
I have Installed PCL 1.6.0 All-In-One Installer. 
in qt Creator config file Look like this

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "D://opencv//install//include" /
               "D://PCL1.6.0//include//pcl-1.6" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//Eigen//include" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//Boost//include" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//VTK//include//vtk-5.8" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//FLANN//include" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//Qhull//include" /


LIBS += "D://opencv//bin//*.dll" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//3rdParty//VTK//lib//vtk-5.8//*.lib" /
"D://PCL1.6.0//lib//*.lib"
```

and I have got error while compiling 
main.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::PCLVisualizer(std::string const&, bool)'

Comment: Check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065984/embedding-pcl-viewer-on-a-qt-gui-main-window